# Error using NumPy.fromiter() with MySQL query results

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, numpy

I have a very simple query, and I'm trying to convert it into a NumPy array using the fromiter() function.  However, I can't figure out why it's not working, or what the error below means. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np

c.execute("SELECT video_id FROM video")
results = c.fetchall()
D = np.fromiter(results, dtype=float, count=-1) 

ERROR: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

c.execute("SELECT video_id FROM video")
results = c.fetchall()
D = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(results), dtype=float, count=-1)
```

This should extract the values from the tuples in results.

Comment: Thanks afg - your solution is indeed faster!

Answer (score 2):

As before, `results` returns tuples, so you will have to pull the value out of the tuple using `itertools.imap`, or your own iterable adapter.

```
results = itertools.imap(lambda t: t[0], results)
```

But I'm just guessing the index since I don't know what you are querying.

Comment: Keith, really appreciate the help.  This did it, and your suggestions have helped me speed up this routine by over 35%.

Comment: `lambda` is slow. If you want to use `imap`, use `operator.itemgetter(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert with MySQL, but it looks like results is ending up as a list where each element is a sequence, like `results = [(foo, bar), (baz, bid)]`, and those items aren't valid numpy array values.

Make sure that each element of results is actually a float, and not, say, a float in a tuple.